Why does my deployment fail with an error about PHP's sqlite3 extension?
Trying to deploy a Shopify webapp using Heroku (following Shopify documentation) I am pushing from a branch (to test before merging into master) running git push heroku <branch name>:refs/head/main. This fails on step 10 of 15:
remote: Step 10/15 : RUN composer install
remote:  ---> Running in 6591d6b4b644
remote: Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
remote: Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
remote: Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. It is recommended that you run `composer update` or `composer update <package name>`.
remote: Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.
remote:
remote:   Problem 1
remote:     - Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-sqlite3 * but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's sqlite3 extension.
remote:
remote: To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:


In PHP.ini I changed the extension directory to its location on my machine. I uncommented the line ";sqlite3" which caused issues, so I reverted this change.

Composer update responds with:

Nothing to modify in lock file

and:

Nothing to install, update, or remove


I tried brew reinstall sqlite and have the most up-to-date version.

My application uses MySQL (not SQLite), so I removed the SQLite requirement from composer.json. The app works on local hosting (Shopify), but I encounter the same error when I push the changes.


Is this related to Heroku, Docker containers, my code, or something else? My post in Shopify community and Heroku ticket haven't received answers.

Did you git add [..] and git commit [..]  your updated composer.json without the ext-sqlite3 requirement (as mentioned by your step 4.) ... before you tried to git push [..] to the heroku remote again?

@NicolaiFröhlich Yes. I double-checked on git kraken; the updated JSON file is on the commit history.

Did you manually remove the dependency from the composer.json with a text editor? If yes you'll have to update the lock-file composer.lock aswell and commit that, too. This can be done with composer update --lock. Otherwise - while your composer.json was updated - your composer.lock would still contain the dependency on ext-sqlite3 and therefore trigger the error after push.

@NicolaiFröhlich that did it! After combing over the .lock file there was a library used for sqlite3 even though there were no other mentions. Removing this line cause a successful build. I now have a 500 server error but thank you for your help!


Manually remove the ext-sqlite3 dependency from your composer.json with a text editor

Update your composer.lock lock-file with command composer update --lock

Commit both file changes to your local git repository
git add composer.json composer.lock
git commit -m 'Remove SQLite3 PHP extension'


Push your changes to the Heroku git remote
git push heroku <branch name>



